# Using the output of a form that is already appearing based on a previous condition for a calculation

Tags: php, html

I am writing code for a running pace calculator, if there is any wind you have the option of factoring this into your calculation altering the time depending on if its a headwind or a tailwind

Part of HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" id="windspeed" name="windspeed" value="windspeed">
<label for="windspeed">Any Wind?</label></p>
```

PHP SCRIPT:

So this part of the PHP works, its creates all of the fields with the values I need to calculate pace lost/gained in headwind tailwind:

```
$max=($_POST['distance']/$_POST['laplength']);
if (!empty($_POST['windspeed'])&&(empty($_POST['elevation'])))
{
    echo "<p><label for=\"Windspeedvalue\">Wind Speed (mph): </label>
    <input type=\"number\" id=\"Windspeedvalue\" name=\"Windspeedvalue\"></p> <br/>
    <label for=\"height\">Height(cm):</label><input type=\"number\" id=\"height\" name=\"height\"></p><br/>
    <label for=\"weight\">Weight(Kg):</label><input type=\"number\" id=\"weight\" name=\"weight\"></p><br/>";


    $counter=1;
    while($counter<=$max)

    {
        if (!empty($_POST['windspeed'])&&(empty($_POST['elevation'])))
        {

            echo "<br/>
            <label for=\"WindDirection\">Lap $counter:</label>
            <select name=\"WindDirection\">
            <option value=\"\">Wind Direction...</option>
            <option value=\"Tailwind $counter\">Tailwind</option>
            <option value=\"Headwind $counter\">Headwind</option>
            </select>"; 

            $counter++;

        }
        echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Winddirectionhidden\" value=\"Winddirectionhidden\"><br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
    elseif (!empty($_POST['windspeed'])&&(!empty($_POST['elevation'])))
{
    echo "<p><label for=\"Windspeedvalue\">Wind Speed (mph): </label>
    <input type=\"number\" id=\"Windspeedvalue\" name=\"Windspeedvalue\"></p><br/>
    <label for=\"height\">Height(cm):</label><input type=\"number\" id=\"height\" name=\"height\"></p><br/>
    <label for=\"weight\">Weight(Kg):</label><input type=\"number\" id=\"weight\" name=\"weight\"></p><br/>";
}
```

However, when I try to use this to alter the pace in the output table. It only reads in the header title, its not reaching the echo TEST values so I know its something to do with the second if/elseif statement or after the wind direction is set.

```
if (!empty(($_POST['Windspeedvalue'])&&($_POST['Winddirectionhidden'])))
    {

        $max=$_POST['distance']/$_POST['laplength'];
        $totalseconds=($_POST['minutes']*60)+($_POST['seconds']);
        $paceinseconds=$totalseconds/$max;
        $maxint=(integer)$max;
        $pacelost=$_POST['Windspeedvalue']*$_POST['Height']*$_POST['Weight']*1.275;
        $pacegained=$_POST['Windspeedvalue']*$_POST['Height']*$_POST['Weight']*(1.275/2);
        $totalflattime=$totalseconds-$pacelost+$pacegained;
        $flattimeperlap=$totalflattime/$_POST['distance'];
        $laptimeinheadwind=$flattimeperlap-($pacelost/$_POST['distance']);
        $laptimeintailwind=$flattimeperlap+($pacegained/$_POST['distance']);

        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>Lap Number</th><th>Time</th></tr>";



        for($counter=1;$counter<=$maxint;$counter++)
        {


            if(isset($_POST['WindDirection']))
            {
                $tempperunitseconds=$unitpace*$counter;
                $tempminutes=($tempperunitseconds/60);
                $outminutes=(integer)$tempminutes;
                $outseconds=(integer)(($tempminutes-$outminutes)*60);
                printf("<tr><td>%02s</td><td>%02s.%02s</td></td>",$counter,$outminutes,$outseconds);
            }
            $direction=$_POST['WindDirection'];
            if($direction=="Headwind")
            {
                echo 'TEST1';
                $tempperunitseconds=$laptimeintailwind*$counter;
                $tempminutes=($tempperunitseconds/60);
                $outminutes=(integer)$tempminutes;
                $outseconds=(integer)(($tempminutes-$outminutes)*60);
                printf("<tr><td>%02s</td><td>%02s.%02s</td></td>",$counter,$outminutes,$outseconds);
            }

            elseif($direction=="Tailwind")
            {
                echo 'TEST2';
                $tempperunitseconds=$laptimeinheadwind*$counter;
                $tempminutes=($tempperunitseconds/60);
                $outminutes=(integer)$tempminutes;
                $outseconds=(integer)(($tempminutes-$outminutes)*60);
                printf("<tr><td>%02s</td><td>%02s.%02s</td></td>",$counter,$outminutes,$outseconds);
                };
            }


        echo "</table>";

    }
```

Comment: Does your input meet the conditions of that if statement? Test that by echoing something in there that you'll recognize on the page. Then wrap the windspeed value variable with some sort of string concatenation and take a look at its value if it's null that could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not into PHP but isn't the problem in the value attribute of your WindDirection? In the value you have probably 'Headwind/Tailwind X' but your if statement tries to compare it with 'Headwind/Tailwind'. Not sure which of these is correct but you need to do one of following

- Change the value attribute of your option element
- Change the if statement to do equality comparison with 'Headwind/Tailwind $counter' or based on 'startsWith' logic

Anyway at the beginning you could try to echo $direction before if statements to find out the real value.